# PHPUnit and stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, phpunit

I am implementing PHPUnit  in my system. 
But most of the logic part is handled in stored proecdure/
How do i write stored procedure for them?

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit has it's focus on PHP-testing. Calling a stored procedure in a database doesn't change that, you can still test your PHP-code. You PHPUnit-test can't test all the logic inside the stored procedure, but it can test the black box.

If you use PostgreSQL as your database, you could take a look at [pgTAP](http://pgtap.org/) for unit testing inside your database.

Comment: A specialized tool like pgTAP prob is a good choice, but you could try using PHPUnit as well. Simply use it to call the procedure against a test database and use it to verify the results are what is expected.